# How is a deep learning network with multiple passes to determine its fitness called?

Tags: deep-learning

Sorry if this has already been answered, I am quite new to deep learning and especially to the specific terms.

I am looking into deep learning at the moment, and I found a video done by Sethbling where he shows a deep neural network he has trained that is able to "play Mario". Here is a link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qv6UVOQ0F44

What is troubling to me is that all the documents I found about NNs are the kind of networks that require a single pass to determine their fitness, or the error. However, this is more a "feed those return values to this network until this condition is met (character doesn't go forward anymore or has come to the end of the level), then evaluate its fitness".

How is this specific kind of learning and way of evaluating a network called ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is process where the error is not known in the beginning or there is no "real" error signal. The goal is to iteratively learn the function. An example for that is [Reinforcement Learning.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning)

What he did there is Reinforcement Learning combined with a Deep Neural Net. In essence you have a set of actions $a$ (up, down, etc.), states $s$ (the screen) and a reward signal $r$. Now you want to find the optimal policy $\pi$ is found. Possibly Deep [Q Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-learning), which works like this (brief description):

1. Feedforward pass for the current state $s$ to get predicted Q-values for all actions.
2. Feedforward pass for the following state $s’$ and find maximum over all  outputs $\underset{a'}{max} \ Q(s’, a’)$.
3. Set Q-value target for action to $r + \gamma \underset{a'}max \ Q(s’, a’)$ (use the max calculated in step 2). For all remaining actions set the Q-value target to the same as returned from step 1, which makes the error $0$
4. Update the weights using backpropagation.

Where $\gamma$ is a discount factor for future rewards.